# Log4net is not writing to file

Tags: file, log4net

I followed youtube videos and articles on net and implemented this. But it never writes to my log file. Tried with all suggestions around many forums with no use.
not sure where I went wrong. I had this inside class library.

app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        
<configuration>
 <configSections> 

<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net><appender name="myLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >


<file value="D:\\Log4NetLog.txt" /><layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">


<conversionPattern value="%date %level - %message%n" /></layout></appender>

<logger name="myLog"><level value="ALL"></level><appender-ref ="myLogAppender" />

</logger></log4net></configuration>
```

and in the Assembly.info.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "app.config", Watch = true)]
```

and in the class file:

```
ILog mylog = LogManager.GetLogger("myLog");
```

string xx = "tokensalt";
mylog.Info(xx);

Comment: tried using log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(ConfigurationManager.GetSection( "log4net") as XmlElement); before ILOG in the class file. But did not work

Comment: all logging properties such as IsDebugEnabled == false

Answer (score 0):

If you configuration is in you app.config, you do not need to specify the file in the Configurator:

```
 [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]
```

Also the watch is not very usefull, when you change the app.config file. The applpication will restart anyway and the file will be reloaded.

If that is not working, I would guess that the path you logging to is not accessible by the web user you are logging with.

```
->>> <file value="D:\\Log4NetLog.txt"
```

Make sure you choose a path where you have access.

Answer (score 0):

Use the file appender and not the rolling appender, the rolling appender was made for backup purposes, for example if your file exceeds 10mb then it will write to your rolling appender and you can decide how many files of 10mb you write there, from the log4net site:

> RollingFileAppender can roll log files based on size or date or both
>   depending on the setting of the RollingStyle property. When set to
>   Size the log file will be rolled once its size exceeds the
>   MaximumFileSize. When set to Date the log file will be rolled once the
>   date boundary specified in the DatePattern property is crossed. When
>   set to Composite the log file will be rolled once the date boundary
>   specified in the DatePattern property is crossed, but within a date
>   boundary the file will also be rolled once its size exceeds the
>   MaximumFileSize. When set to Once the log file will be rolled when the
>   appender is configured. This effectively means that the log file can
>   be rolled once per program execution.

Here is a working web.config example that should work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.appender.FileAppender">
            <file value="C:\MyLogs\MyLogFile.txt"/>
            <appendToFile value="true"/>
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%logger] %level - %message%newline%exception"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>
<root>
        <level value="DEBUG"></level>
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"></appender-ref>
    </root>
</log4net>
```